# chosen not working for select drop down which is not displayed by default

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a select box in a div which is displayed none by default and on some click event the display property of div is changed to block but the select drop down is not displaying and is showing empty space. I have called the chosen() method for the select box in the same triggered function where I am changing the visibility of div.

Here is the code of my issue.

```
<div class="controls" style="display:none" id="Department-11">
    <select multiple="" class="chosen-select1" id="form-field-select-4" data-placeholder="Choose a Department...">
        <option value="Management">Senior Management</option>
        <option value="Legal">Legal</option>
        <option value="Operations">Operations</option>
        <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
        <option value="R&D">R&D</option>
        <option value="Sales & Marketing">Sales & Marketing</option>
        <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        <option value="Customer Service">Customer Service</option>
        <option value="Pro Services">Pro Services</option>
        <option value="HR">HR</option>
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showselect();">
    Show select
</a>
```

And the JS code is

```
function showselect() {
    $('#Department-11').show();
    $(".chosen-select1").chosen();
}
```

Comment: Try to make `chosen()` works alone. Replace your link with this `<a href="javascript:showSelect()"></a>` and in showSelect, just `$(".chosen-select1").chosen();`. You must check if the issue is only comming from the plugin or not. Also, the doc says to put the empty option in first place, not last one.

Comment: I have explored this issue and found that the width comes to 0px for 
<div id="form_field_select_4_chosen" class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 0px;" title="">


<input class="default" type="text" style="width: 0px;" autocomplete="off" value="Choose a Department...">

Comment: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/795

Comment: Added a hack as 
   .chosen-container {
    width: 220px !important;
   }

Comment: _By default, Chosen attempts to match the width of the select box you are replacing. If your select is hidden when Chosen is instantiated, you must specify a width or the select will show up with a width of 0._ [Here is a list of chosen configuration](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html). As a clean solution, you could use the `width` option in chosen to give it an appropriate value.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add css `.chosen-container { width: 220px !important; }`

Comment: This works, but would still like to know why this happens in the first place. Thanks

Answer (score 30):

Another solution is setting element width in initial method as below.

```
$(".chosen-select1").chosen({ width:"95%" });
```

Comment: You saved the day for me!

Comment: But it means we have to specify width in script, which defeats the purpose of having CSS files.

Comment: This is a good approach since it allows the Chosen block to always be full width of the container, whatever its eventual size. I've set mine to be width 99% and it works nicely.

Comment: This is the best solution as it does not involve modifying the chosen.css and therefore the width is not hard coded to the one size for all chosen dropdowns.

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. In your Jquery add this line. It works for me.

$(".chosen-select1").val("Legal").trigger("chosen:updated");